# How to access the Problems database

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've got a large codebase with many existing warnings. While we fix them as time allows there are just too many so we decided to ignore most and just prevent new warnings from entering the codebase. Someone wrote a pretty fragile python script that compares the warnings in our dev trunk to warnings in a feature branch to help tease out any new warnings. It seems like I could probably write a vscode extension to do this same sort of thing. (or there might be one already) I'd like to be able to either be able to ignore specific warnings and remove them from the Problems tab (file/line/warning text) without having to modify source code (i.e. no #pragmas or comments) or I'd like to be able to access the list of warnings so I can save out the existing ones and do a diff with the current set. Any pointers?

Comment: so you decide to keep subtle bugs in the code and spend time to filter the warning messages, just spend time to fix the warnings, it will save you a lot of work later on

Comment: This is not a very helpful comment and does not address the quest. Warnings are generally conversion from uint8_t to int and similar. They are known to not be bugs for the target platform and the technical debt is far too large to fix at once within the budget and time for the project. Try working in a real environment and learn when you can get away with such widespread changes and when it's not feasible.

Comment: why do you need to filter the old warnings, the warnings in the new code  you write are visible in the editor, most likely while you type

Comment: Have a look at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.problems-copy. It is pretty easy to copy and filter the problems.

Comment: @riov8 it will also show existing warnings that way. The idea is to be able to use the Problems tab before a commit to double check for things missed when code was written. Currently it's not useful as it shows hundreds of warning from the most recent build